# PHP kohana framework template rendering issue - blank page

Tags: php, kohana

I have created one function to fetch the user inbox message and display it using "user-profile-messages" templates. 
Also I have added functionality (in the same function) to deleting bulk inbox message if user clicked on delete all button.
But after deleting all messages, page/template is not redering. Please let me know what could be the reason.

I am rendering page using below method.

```
 $this->template->body = View::factory("user-profile-messages", array(
            "msg" => $msg,
            "messages" => $messages,
        ))->render();
```

I am using Kohana latest version.

Comment: Are you `echo`ing `$body` in your template view?

Comment: No. I am using View::factory()->render() method to display the templates.

Comment: `render()` just converts View object to a string. Alex means that you need to display `$body` var somewhere in your `$this->template` View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, *if* you're not extending the template controller, then your code should be:

```
$view = View::factory("user-profile-messages", array(
    "msg" => $msg,
    "messages" => $messages,
));

$this->response->body($view)
```

Output is set by `$this->response->body($view)`. Calling render isn't needed as it has a __toString method.

---

If you're extending the template controller, which it looks like you are. It renders output automatically unless you explicity tell it not to:

```
$this->auto_render = FALSE;
```

By default, it's going to render the template *template* with a variable *body* which will contain your view.